# Running PHPMyAdmin under PHP 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm running PHP 5.4.45. I cannot upgrade to a later version for irreverent reasons. I've checked the PHPMyAdmin downloads page, and none of them work with my version. What are my options here? I get the following error message whatever version I'm using.

> PHP 5.5+ is required.
>       Currently installed version is: 5.4.45

Comment: a) solving the reasons and upgrading - which would be the best case anyway -  b) getting a lot of manpower and backporting phpMyAdmin c) looking for a *really really old* version of phpMyAdmin (note the security risks) d) run it on a different server/vm/container where you *can* use a current version of php

Comment: I can't upgrade to a later version. My hosting provider also hosts other websites which are incompatible with PHP 5+

Comment: alright then, if the reason is not extremely important legacy code, but an extremely outdated hosting provider, i would very strongly suggest getting a different one.

Comment: ...Or e) using a real SQL editor like MySQL Workbench, SequelPro, or DBForge

Comment: @JeremyHarris we're at e) ;). and i'm confused how you can write "real SQL editor" and fail to mention the only true one: the mysql shell-client ;)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann LOL, I was just saying there are *better* ways of accessing and managing a database. PHPMyAdmin is good for beginners, but it has it's limits. (updated to e:)

Comment: 1. PHP 5.4 [has been EOL for nearly 18 months](http://php.net/eol.php). If your host won't upgrade, get a new host because when new security patches come out, you're not getting them 2. [PHPMyAdmin 4.0 still runs under 5.2 or later](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) (soon to be EOL as well)

Answer (score 1):

You need to download version of phpMyAdmin 4 or other versions (Released 2017-03-29, see release notes for details.
Older version compatible with PHP 5.2 and MySQL 5. Does not support PHP 5.5 or newer. Was supported until April 1, 2017) then you can resolve this error.

link : [https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/]

I hope this solution helps you.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using phpMyAdmin-4.4.15.10 , all others give the message "PHP 5.5+ is required".
Also why they don't write the supported php version on the download page is beyond me...